# Show that $g(y) = \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx$ is not continuous at $y =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Exercise 7.5.17 (Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl): Define 
>   $$f(x) = \left\{
>   \begin{array}{lr}
>     \frac{2xy}{x^4+y^2} & \text{if} & (x,y) \not= (0,0)\\
>     0 & \text{if} & (x,y) =(0,0)
>   \end{array}
> \right.
>  $$
>
> Show that $g(y) = \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx$ is not continuous at $y =0$. Note: Feel free to use what you know about $\arctan$ from calculus, in particular that $\frac{d}{ds} [\arctan(s)] = \frac1{1+s^2}$.

From the previous exercises, I know that $f$ is continuous at one variable, fixing another variable. In addition, I also know that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Since the question gives us the use of the derivative of $\arctan$ as a hint, I guess that I need to use trigonometric substitution to compute the integral (?), but I am not really sure. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: why not try a $u$ substitution, can you think of a function such that $du$ would be the numerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
Let $x^2 = t$

$$\int_0^1\frac{2xy}{x^4 + y^2}dx = \int_0^1\frac{y}{(t^2 + y^2)}dt = \arctan(\frac{1}{y})$$

Can you complete the rest?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By FTC, I get arctan$(\frac1{\sqrt{y}})$. Then, should I conclude that $g(y)$ is not continuous at $y=0$ since it is undefined?

Comment: There's an extra $\sqrt y$ you're missing

Comment: Sorry, had made an error, made the necessary edits

Answer (score 0):

For $y >0$ we have $\int_0^{1}f(x,y)dx=y\int_0^{1} \frac u {u^{2}+y^{2}} du$ by the substitution $u=x^{2}$. Hence $\int_0^{1}f(x,y)dx=\arctan (\frac u y)|_0^{1}=\arctan \frac 1 y$. Can you proceed?